# Checkbox Values from Local Storage when Editing Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have stored values from a html-form to `localStorage` and I get the data back from `localStorage` to form for editing. Checked checkbox values (MaterialName) are stored to `localStorage` as an array. Original checkbox values are coming from database via ajax. What do I need to do to get those values in `localStorage` match values from database, and to be checked again when editing form? Or is it even possible this way?

```
// localstorage value
{
  "FormID": 150,
  "CreateDate": "2019-09-17T00:00:00",
  "FormFiller": "JOkuMuu",
  "CustomerName": "Wsoy",
  "CustomerContact": "Masa",
  "WorkName": "Lajitelmapakkaus",
  "ReadyToDate": "2019-09-19T00:00:00",
  "Instructions": "Tarkasta kirjat ",
  "Amount": 50,
  "MaterialName": "Xpohja,Tarra"
}
```

This is function to get all materials from database:

```js
function addMaterials(material) {
  $MaterialName.append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + material.MaterialName + '">' + material.MaterialName + ' </input>');
}
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/materials',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(materials) {
    $.each(materials, function(i, material) {
      addMaterials(material);
    });
  },
  error: function() {
    alert: ('Virhe ladattaessa')
  }
});
```

This is function I tried to get checked values to be re-checked:

```js
$(function() {
  //bring data from localStorage
  var lsdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
  //put data to form
  $('#formid').val(lsdata.FormID);
  $('#createdate').val(lsdata.CreateDate);
  $('#formfiller').val(lsdata.FormFiller);
  $('#customerlist').empty().append(lsdata.CustomerName.split(',').map(c => new Option(c, c)));
  $('#contact').val(lsdata.CustomerContact);
  $('#worklist').empty().append(lsdata.WorkName.split(',').map(c => new Option(c, c)));
  $('#readytodate').val(lsdata.ReadyToDate);
  $('#instructions').val(lsdata.Instructions);
  $('#amount').val(lsdata.Amount);
  $('#materiallist').append('<input type="checkbox" checked>' + lsdata.MaterialName + ' </input>');
});
```

Everything else is working except MaterialName. It is adding new value with Xpohja,Tarra. I want it to add 'checked' to those Xpohja and Tarra, not new value.

Comment: You mean that you don't see the `MaterialName` from the `localStorage` next to the input? (This line:   `$('#materiallist').append('<input type="checkbox" checked>' + lsdata.MaterialName + ' </input>');`)

Answer (score 1):

Give each checkbox a id with same as of materiaName like below:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="Xpohja">Xpohja <br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="Tarra">Tarra<br>
```

Now when you are fetching the value from localStorage to edit the form then you can convdert the json string to map or array and iterate over it to set the checked attribute as below:

```
$('#id').attr('checked', true)
```

Comment: Values are coming from another database, so I don't know how I can put ids to every checkbox? Values are not "hardcoded".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment but do you mean you want the checkbox value to be set to 'Xpohja,Tarra' ? Or you want two new checkboxes? One with 'Xpohja' and another one with 'Tarra'?

I have left a solution below if you wanted a checkbox with the values.

```js
var lsdata = "Xpohja,Tarra";
 
$('#materiallist').append('<input type="checkbox" checked> </input>');

$('#materiallist input').val(lsdata);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="materiallist"></div>
```

Comment: Checkboxes are already coming from database, I want those values in LocalStorage to be checked, not new checkboxes. User has checked values xpohja and tarra and when editing form afterwards, those same checkboxes should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lsdata = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
var chkArray = lsdata.MaterialName.split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < chkArray.length; i++){
   $('input[type="checkbox"]').find('[value="'+ chkArray[i] +'"]').attr('checked', true)
}
```

Comment: can you share jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/HeiJoe/qjx8eo0t/  I haven't use jsfidlle before, so I don't know is that done properly.

Comment: I can't have values hardcoded to inputs, because all values are coming from other database, see function "addMaterials" in original question. Can I compare LocalStorage MaterialName values to MaterialName values from database and put 'checked' if values are same? I don't know if that is even possible, but last jsfiddle didn't help me enough, I still need all values from database, if user needs to add new materials when editing form.